# Возврат значения в переменную из метода

Tags: java

В результате работы метода переменной `String b1` должно присваиваться значение `b`. Но этого не происходит.

```
public class Decoder {
    public String decode(String a,String b) {
        CharSequence[] text = { "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n"
            ,"o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z" };
        String[] morze = { ".-","_...","_._.","_..",".",".._.","__.","...."
                ,"..",".___","_._","._..","__","_.","___",".__.","__._","._."
                ,"...","-",".._","..._",".__","_.._","_.__","__.." };
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            if (a.contains(text[i])) {
                b += morze[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(":" + b);
        return b;
    }
}

soundButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String a = textText.getText();
        String b1 = "";
        d.decode(a, b1);
        System.out.println(b1);
        morzeText.setText(b1);
        s.play();
    }
});
```

Comment: эм... а с чего оно должно присвоится? вы бы хоть `b1 = d.decode(a, b1);` писали. Ну и алгоритм совсем неправильный...

Answer (score 2):

В строке `b += morze[i];` в переменную `b` присваивается ссылка на новую строку, значение которой получается конкатенацией старого значения `b` и `morze[i]`. От того, что вы присваиваете переменной `b` ссылку на новую строку, исходная строка `b1` никоим образом не меняется. Поэтому имеет смысл собирать строку с нуля в методе и возвращать её в `return`, после чего сохранять полученное значение в `b1`:

```
public String decode(String a) {
    String b = "";
```

и

```
b1 = d.decode(a);
```

А теперь по самому коду:

1. Вы используете неправильный алгоритм получения закодированной строки. Нужно проходить по всем символам исходной строки и для каждого символа находить соответствующую строку в азбуке Морзе. Можно каждый раз искать индекс соответствующего символа в `text` и брать строку из `morze` с таким же индексом, а можно создать `HashMap` для пар `символ -> строка Морзе`.
2. Превращение букв в символы азбуки Морзе, на мой взгляд, стоит расценивать как кодирование, а не декодирование, поэтому методу больше подойдёт название `encode`.
3. Инициализировать массивы `text` и `morze` при каждом вызове метода достаточно расточительно. Имеет смысл их инициализировать ровно один раз (либо при инициализации класса, либо при первом вызове метода). А массив `text` можно в целях экономии превратить в массив `char`-ов.
4. Создавать на каждой итерации новую строку также достаточно расточительно. Для таких целей лучше подойдёт `StringBuilder`.

В итоге код можно переписать так:

```
public class Decoder
{
    private static final char[] chars = { 'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',
            'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z' };
    private static final String[] morze = { ".-","_...","_._.","_..",".",".._.","__.",
            "....","..",".___","_._","._..","__","_.","___",".__.","__._","._."
            ,"...","-",".._","..._",".__","_.._","_.__","__.." };

    private static final HashMap<Character, String> charToMorze = new HashMap<>();
    static
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        {
            charToMorze.put(chars[i], morze[i]);
        }
    }

    public static String encode(String text)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = text.charAt(i);
            if (charToMorze.containsKey(c))
            {
                sb.append(charToMorze.get(c));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

---

Если алфавит останется таким же (от `a` до `z`), то код можно несколько упростить:

```
public class Decoder
{
    private static final String[] morze = { ".-","_...","_._.","_..",".",".._.","__.",
            "....","..",".___","_._","._..","__","_.","___",".__.","__._","._."
            ,"...","-",".._","..._",".__","_.._","_.__","__.." };

    public static String encode(String text)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
        {
            int index = text.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if (index >= 0 && index < morze.length)
            {
                sb.append(morze[index]);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

C использованием stream-ов из Java 8 второй вариант можно записать и так:

```
public static String encode(String text)
{
    return text.chars().map(c -> c - 'a').filter(c -> c >=0 && c < morze.length)
            .mapToObj(c -> morze[c]).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Comment: а ещё бы массив chars вообще можно убрать было, да и HashMap тоже. Чем вам например `sb.append(morze[c - 'a'])` не понравилось.

Comment: @pavel была такая мысль. Однако если вдруг автор решит добавить в алфавит ещё символов, то такой подход сломается. Поэтому вариант с вычитанием, думаю, добавлю как альтернативный с пометкой "если не собираетесь менять алфавит и порядок символов в нём".